# SummingMergeTree partitioned by tuple

Tags: optimization, tuples, clickhouse

Trying to create SummingMergeTree partitioned by tuple like this:

```
CREATE TABLE partitioned_by_tuple(d Date, x UInt8, w String, y UInt8) ENGINE SummingMergeTree (y) PARTITION BY (d, x) ORDER BY (d, x, w);
```

Inserting data in table:

```
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-02 │ 1 │ first │ 3 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-01 │ 2 │ first │ 2 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-01 │ 1 │ first │ 1 │
│ 2000-01-01 │ 1 │ first │ 2 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
```

Trying to optimize table:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE partitioned_by_tuple;
```

And expect to be like this:

```
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-02 │ 1 │ first │ 3 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-01 │ 2 │ first │ 2 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
┌──────────d─┬─x─┬─w─────┬─y─┐
│ 2000-01-01 │ 1 │ first │ 3 │
└────────────┴───┴───────┴───┘
```

But table does not changes after optimization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/#optimize

> If you specify FINAL, optimization will be performed even when all the data is already in one part.

You need to specify `FINAL` at the end to force the optimization to be perfomed inside one part.

Edit:

After this PR https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/2599 OPTIMIZE will be able to use FINAL to merge all parts.

Now it's merged.

Comment: It throws exception when i'm doing "OPTIMIZE TABLE partitioned_by_tuple FINAL": FINAL flag for OPTIMIZE query is meaningful only with specified PARTITION.

Comment: Yeah, since all the merge selectors don't consider partitions that only have one part, thus `FINAL` won't have any effect. I wonder if that's a practical issue. At least it can be extended trivially.

Comment: Yes, it's practical issue. I'm trying to find a way to improve my system of analytics